# Python strings and int

Tags: python

I've been following an online course and I've ran into a road block. I wanted to try to see if a list of integers is greater than one given integer. I keep getting the error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`. Help?

Here's my attempt:

```
    def numCount(someList, comparison):
        returnVal = []
        if numList >= comparison:
                returnVal += numList
        return returnVal

    numList=[0, 2, 4, 5, 10]
    print(numCount(someList, 9))
```

Comment: `numList` is a list right now, and `comparison` is an int - do you know how to get an int out of the list `numList`?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up your variables, did you mean `print(numCount(numList, 9))` and `if someList >= comparison:`. Note: You can do this with `filter()`, e.g. `return list(filter(lambda x: x >= comparison, someList))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must iterate over each item in the list and compare them:

```
def numCount(someList, comparison):
    returnVal = []
    for elt in someList:
        if elt >= comparison:
            returnVal.append(elt)
    return returnVal

numList=[0, 2, 4, 5, 10]
print(numCount(numList, 9))
```

#### output:

`[10]`

The output is a list of the values in `numList`that are greater or equal to the comparison integer.

Comment: Thank you, sir. As a beginner, this helped me greatly. Upvoted^

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support comparing a list to an int mainly because it doesnt make sense. Do you mean you want to see if the sum of a list of ints is larger than a given int? Or do you want to find all ints in a list that are larger than a given number and return a list containing those ints?